# Windows Update KB2779768 Installation Failure on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, installation

I purchased a new 64 bit computer with Windows 8 (not Pro) installed in December 2012. Today I am running Window-8 updates.  All updates have a Status of Succeeded except one update that downloads but does not install.  In Control Panel, Windows Updates ...

After downloading, the install begins then FAILS about 25% (according to the progress bar) into the install.  I have read on other forums and have learned that this particular update (KB2779768) consists of 4 updates in one. So far I have read about users who have completely reinstalled Windows-8 and the problem persists.

There were stories on the other forums about users spending an hour and a half (plus) on the  telephone with Microsoft support to get the update successfully installed but there we no details provided.

The KB2779768 update appears to be a rather recent one circa December 2012.  I looked at my Update History Log and see that KB2779768 (Important) is the first entry in the log and failed the day the operating system was installed (December 12/18/2012).  My computer appears to be working fine.

The install failure delivered the following error: Code 8000FFFF

My questions are:

1. Has anyone heard about a resolution to this problem?
2. Does Microsoft plan an automated solution to the failure of KB2779768?
3. Would you look in your Windows Update Log to see if KB2779768 installed successfully?

I hope I've asked the question clearly and correctly - this is the first question I have submitted to this forum. Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Comment: I would contact Microsoft for assistance if other people have reported success in installing this update after doing so.  Without additional information we are unlikely able to provide any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it manually.

First, here's the page for the update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779768

One of the things that page tells you is that you can go to the download center and download the update yourself. Thus we reach this web page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=KB2779768

You said you're running x64 Windows 8, so that bring us here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35852

The four updates listed on that page are:

1. http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/0/8B0BB23A-47BA-41A3-93C7-5EDAF8F2D815/Windows8-RT-KB2779768-x64.msu
2. http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/0/8B0BB23A-47BA-41A3-93C7-5EDAF8F2D815/Windows8-RT-KB2782419-x64.msu
3. http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/0/8B0BB23A-47BA-41A3-93C7-5EDAF8F2D815/Windows8-RT-KB2783251-x64.msu
4. http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/0/8B0BB23A-47BA-41A3-93C7-5EDAF8F2D815/Windows8-RT-KB2784160-x64.msu

Try downloading them and installing them one at a time. One or more of them will likely fail and complain about something, hopefully something specific. It could even be something along the lines of "That's already installed".

Good luck!

Since you're now getting a specific error code, here's the KB article that tells how to deal with it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946414

Comment: Also, running appwiz.cpl, clicking View Installed Updates and then pasting that KB # into the search window shows me that my machine installed the hotfix on 1/3/2013.

Comment: +1 for proving me wrong, I love this board.

Comment: Nothing's proven yet, but thanks. Let's see if they can figure out which hotfix isn't installing and why not. :)

Comment: Mark, please see my comments above.

Comment: @user184390 - I don't see any new comments, sorry. Which MSU file won't install, and what is the error message it gives you when you try?

Comment: Hi Mark, I left a rather long response yesterday, but I guess I keyed it in the wrong text area and it got lost.

The short story is I did the manual install you suggested, #1 did not install.
However, #'s 2, 3 and 4 did.
After #4 installed, Windows 8 did a restart.

I attempted to install #1 a second time, but it failed (again).
There was no reason given for the failure of the #1 install.

Thank you for all your effort.
If you think of anything else to try, I would appreciate it.

user184390

Comment: Just received 13 more updates to be installed and installed 11, of the two that did not install, one was our old friend KB2779768, the second was KB2785094 (both Important).  The install failure delivered the following error: Code 8000FFFF  I found this repair tool at: http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=8000ffff do you think this repair program would do the job?

Comment: @user184390 - it might fix it, but I've never heard of wiki-errors.com, so I would hesitate to run executable code from them. Instead, take a look at the MS KB article on the failure, which is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946414 - it has a self-fix thing as well as manual instructions. I'll update my answer as well. You should add the error code to your question.

Comment: @Mark Allen I ran the support.microsoft.com/kb/94641 and selected the aggressive option - the Microsoft Fix it 50203 returned the following message:  "This Microsoft Fix it does not apply to your operating system or application version."  Then I tried without the aggressive option and received the same message.

Comment: Then I followed the Microsoft Windows Update Troubleshooter using the Code 8000FFFF and it ran a fix that reported:  "Troubleshooting has completed  The troubleshooter made some changes to your system.  Try attempting the task you were trying to do before. Problems found Potential Windows Update Database error detected 0x80070490 - Fixed and Windows Update components must be repaired - Fixed"  I looked at the Windows Update Log - It was cleared out.  I restarted Windows 8 and ran the Windows Update -- Windows found the to updates KB2779768 & KB2785094, downloaded - but the install failed.

Comment: I went into safe mode and discovered that the Windows Update database is corrupted with error:  0x80070490 see:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/18ea2b35-487e-437d-821e-8cd6711307e0 - there does not appear to be a cure. I'm considering a Windows 8 refresh.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is a fix from MS ... I'll try this next and keep y'all posted.   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958044

Comment: Hi!  I tried the MS fix - it failed.  So I ran SFC /scannow as they suggested.  SFC found errors in the CSB file (database) -- I ran SFC /scannow three times until there were no errors reported.  Restarted and attempted a Windows Update, it failed with a Code 8000FFFF - starting to feel like a dog chasing his tail here.

Comment: @user184390 wow that is super annoying, I'm sorry for your trouble. I think you're right, time for a Windows 8 refresh, it shouldn't be this much trouble to update a computer. (and it's normally not.)

Comment: @Mark Allen An update: Spent 6 hours on the phone yesterday with Microsoft Support - no resolution yet - they will be calling me back later today.  Is there a badge for IT martyr? :-)

Comment: @user184390 - That's terrible. Didn't you try the Windows 8 Refresh?

Comment: I thought I'd give them a try - which was a mistake. That will be next after I cleanup the mess they left. You may not hear from me for a few days.

Answer (score -3):

Welcome to SuperUser!

This:

> an hour and a half (plus) on the telephone with Microsoft support

tells you we **likely** aren't going to be able to help you here.  If it takes the manufacturer an hour and a half to fix the mess, we aren't going to be able to do this in a response to the question.  It sounds like you too are going to have to contact MS about this issue.

Comment: 3.Would you look in your Windows Update Log to see if KB2779768 installed successfully?

Comment: He doesn't use Win7 either. :P

Comment: Sorry, I don't run Windows, I run OS X

Comment: If you are planning on adding to the negative score, engage your brain first and notice the word **LIKELY** in bold, along with the explanation as to **WHY** it **LIKELY** won't be answered here.  That or leave an explanation on why you think this is wrong...